# Using Active Record generators after Mongoid installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB via Mongoid integration, as well as ActiveRecord in a project.  I would like to generate migrations for active record, and Mongoid is the default when I run.

```
rails g migration
```

Any ideas how to specify AR as my default generator for migrations, models, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I answered this (cant really answer it for another 7 hours due to rep). rails g active_record:migration seems to get it

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
rails g active_record:migration
```

Comment: Thanks. I was seeing a weird `error  mongoid [not found]` and run the migration as `rails g active_record:migration ...` instead of just `rails g migration ...` worked ;)

Answer (score 87):

You can config to use ActiveRecord generators in your config/application.rb

```
config.generators do |g| 
  g.orm :active_record 
end
```

Comment: Great tip! Complementing it, after this config, to invoke a mongoid generator, say for a model 'whatever', one would use:
    rails g mongoid:model whatever

Comment: I tried this in my Rails 4.2.2 app but it is not working, I have the same behavior with and without this. Any idea what I should check to make it working?